# CSS: crolling left column with a sticky right column. Works but can't understand why

Tags: html, css, jsx

```
.sticky_show_container {
    width: 100%; 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 150vh;
}

.sticky_show_grid {
    width: 90%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    height: 230vh;
    background-color: aquamarine;
   
}


.sticky_show_header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    position: sticky;
    top: 50%;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

this is the jsx

```
  <div className="sticky_show_container">
            <div className="sticky_show_grid">
                <div  className="sticky_show_content">
                    <Card image={'/1.webp'} title={'villa mosco'} subTitle={'tranquility'} />
                    <Card image={'/1.webp'} title={'villa mosco'} subTitle={'tranquility'} />
                    <Card image={'/1.webp'} title={'villa mosco'} subTitle={'tranquility'} />
                </div>
                <div className="sticky_show_header">
                    <p>more villas</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Each card is 50vh, I set the first container to the height of the cards.
The sticky column has a text in the start of the container, that as we scroll down aligns with the last card, then we move to the next content.

Not sure why it works that way, is there a better way to do it, or can you help me understand?

Comment: Could you post the (**relevant**) *[mcve]* HTML created from the JSX, along with the CSS above? To be clear the CSS works with the HTML, generated by your framework and the JSX therein, the HTML is what the browser "sees" once the page is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you search for `position: sticky` information.

As [W3](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) quotes:

> A sticky element toggles between relative and fixed, depending on the scroll position. It is positioned relative until a given offset position is met in the viewport - then it "sticks" in place (like position:fixed).